# How can I do a "FOR JSON" with 2 joins

Tags: sql-server, json

I can't get this to work properly. I have 4 tables: Products, Suppliers, X_Product_Suppliers and Comments. I want to query them all and put them into JSON using the following query:

```
WITH Products (Id, Name, Price) As (
    SELECT 1, 'First Product', 10
), Suppliers (Id, Name) As (
    SELECT 1, 'Factory1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Factory2'
), Comments (Id, [Text], ProductId) As (
    SELECT 1, 'Good Product', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Fantastic!'  , 1
), X_Product_Supplier (ProductId, SupplierId) As (
    SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 2
)
SELECT Products.*, Suppliers.*, Comments.* FROM Products
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_Product_Supplier ON X_Product_Supplier.ProductId = Products.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Suppliers ON X_Product_Supplier.SupplierId = Suppliers.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments ON Comments.ProductId = Products.Id
FOR JSON AUTO
```

For some reason sql-server will nest the comments under the supplier instead of under the product:

```
   {  
      "Id":1,
      "Name":"First Product",
      "Price":"10",
      "Suppliers":[  
         {  
            "Id":1,
            "Name":"Factory1",
            "Comments":[  //THIS SHOULD BE UNDER PRODUCT, NOT SUPPLIER
               {  
                  "Id":1,
                  "Text":"Good Product",
                  "ProductId":1
               },
               {  
                  "Id":2,
                  "Text":"Fantastic!",
                  "ProductId":1
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "Id":2,
            "Name":"Factory2",
            "Comments":[  //THIS IS NOW DUPLICATE
               {  
                  "Id":1,
                  "Text":"Good Product",
                  "ProductId":1
               },
               {  
                  "Id":2,
                  "Text":"Fantastic!",
                  "ProductId":1
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
```

What I actually want is this:

```
   {  
      "Id":1,
      "Name":"First Product",
      "Price":"10",
      "Suppliers":[  
         {  
            "Id":1,
            "Name":"Factory1"
         },
         {  
            "Id":2,
            "Name":"Factory2"
         }
      ],
      "Comments":[  
               {  
                  "Id":1,
                  "Text":"Good Product",
                  "ProductId":1
               },
               {  
                  "Id":2,
                  "Text":"Fantastic!",
                  "ProductId":1
               }
            ]
   }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You should provide structure of the tables and sample data.

Comment: Change `FOR JSON AUTO` to `FOR JSON PATH` and I think that'll output as you're expecting.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone else is looking for answer here is simple query I have written. Change the query as per your schema and it should give your proper structured result.

```
SELECT Products.*,
(SELECT Suppliers.*
 FROM Suppliers
 WHERE Suppliers.Id = Products.SuppliersId
 FOR JSON AUTO) As Suppliers,
(SELECT Comments.*
 FROM Comments 
 WHERE Comments.ProductId = Products.Id
 FOR JSON AUTO) As Comments
FROM Products
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: This issue plagued me for several days until I stumbled across your explanation.  Thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

I know its late, but i faced with same problem but the answers could not help in filtering the null values in where clause, my solution below

```
SELECT  Products.*, 
        Suppliers.Id as [Suppliers.Id], 
        Suppliers.Name as [Suppliers.Name],
        Comments.Id as [Comments.Id],
        Comments.Text as [Comments.Text],
        Comments.ProductId as [Comments.ProductId] 
FROM Products
LEFT OUTER JOIN X_Product_Supplier ON X_Product_Supplier.ProductId = Products.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Suppliers ON X_Product_Supplier.SupplierId = Suppliers.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Comments ON Comments.ProductId = Products.Id
FOR JSON PATH
```

Tested and working on SQL SERVER 2017

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will convert result table into JSON with columns going in the same order as they appear in `SELECT` statement. It would not make any assumptions of column grouping. To help it Suppliers and Comments can be pre-arranged into JSON objects for each Product:

```
WITH Products (Id, Name, Price) As (
    SELECT 1, 'First Product', 10
), Suppliers (Id, Name) As (
    SELECT 1, 'Factory1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Factory2'
), Comments (Id, [Text], ProductId) As (
    SELECT 1, 'Good Product', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'Fantastic!'  , 1
), X_Product_Supplier (ProductId, SupplierId) As (
    SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 2
)
SELECT Products.*,
    (SELECT Suppliers.*
     FROM Suppliers
     INNER JOIN X_Product_Supplier ON X_Product_Supplier.SupplierId = Suppliers.Id
     WHERE X_Product_Supplier.ProductId = Products.Id
     FOR JSON AUTO, TYPE) As Suppliers,
    (SELECT Comments.*
     FROM Comments
     WHERE Comments.ProductId = Products.Id
     FOR JSON AUTO, TYPE) As Comments
FROM Products
FOR JSON AUTO
```

- Tested on XML as I do not have access to SQL Server 2016 at the moment.
  Please let me know if this does not work.